# How to type EOF in ARMv8 Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, eof, armv8

I am using the ARMv8 instruction set with Aarch64 execution state. The problem I am having, is were supposed to translate C code into assembly, and I am stuck on the following:

```
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    c = getchar();
```

I know the basic setup for the while loop, as well as how to test `c != '\n'` but the issue I have is how to write `EOF` in assembly.
Can i just type

```
cmp c_r, EOF
b.eq skipwhile
```

or is it something else?

Comment: it's a macro in C which most probably expands to -1. Try to find a similar macro or just use -1

Comment: printf("%X\n",EOF);

Comment: and then figure it out from there.

Comment: FYI: You can use `gcc -E infile.c` to preprocess-only your source code. This will replace all macros, include files, etc. There will be a LOT of empty lines, but you'll be seeing what the actual compiler sees, and so macros like EOF will get replaced by, e.g., `(-1)` or something. This can be very useful when you are compiling by hand. (There are similar options on most compilers, if you aren't using `gcc`.) (There are also options to generate assembly, just sayin'... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what code you're using in assembly for `getchar()` -

- If you're just using a call to the assembly version of standard C library `getchar()`, then you can test with the C library's definition of `EOF` - normally `-1`.
- If you're implementing your own `getchar()` in assembly, then you need to match your test to the return value of your `getchar()` implementation when it gets to the end-of-file.